# Looking for VPS Hosting for a LAMP Web Application

Tags: web-hosting, vps, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Trying to find a *Managed VPS Hosting Solution* for a LAMP Web Application.

- The more CPU, RAM, and Disk space the better
- Don't need a huge amount of bandwidth for now
- Would like to be able to easily grow into a stronger server
- Have really responsive, dedicated, smart support staff -- our current hosting is just terrible

My main problem is that I can't even find a non-biased website out there that does a proper comparison of VPS Hosting providers. Can anybody either suggest a reviews/ranking site or a hosting with proven record?

How would *you* go about finding the best hosting service?

Thanks a lot!

Ali

Answer (score 2):

I find judging VPS performance and quality very hard. It’s like shared hosting, you have little control how they run their servers, how much overselling they do and how much guaranteed IO bandwidth you get. Although a good VPS provider could offer failover infrastructure.

But if price is your main concern, I would just go for an unmanaged dedicated hosting. With today’s low prices there is not much difference in price compared to a good VPS. The server specs of those dedicated servers will give you a much more reliable prediction of the performance you will get.

Pricing example: Hetzner in Germany only asks [50 Euro/Month](http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_rootserver/eq4) for an Intel Core i7-920 with 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Linode is one of the better one's

http://www.linode.com/

That's where I've recently started with my first VPS.

Media Temple is another one

http://mediatemple.net/

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I have an account with Linode for my personal blog, but they are *unmanaged*. I'm running my main business web app on this, so I definitely want the expertise of a good support team in case I'm not able to fix something in the middle of the night! I've heard good things about MediaTemple, though they seem to be on the expensive side for the server specs they offer. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali - Ah, okay. I didn't read your qestion properly. Linode definatly isn't the answer. Media temple has one of the best support teams out there as far as I know.